# Can't reach my server from another network

Tags: networking, server, ssh, internet, ping

setting up my own server lead me to a problem, that i can't solve on my own.

My server is a 'Ubuntu-server 14.04.1' and is located behind a 'FR!TZBox 7390'. My ipv4-adress is projected on a ipv6-adress by a DS-Lite-Tunnel.
As i am connected to the internet, i am able to ping 'google.com'. I can also connect to my server from a pc in the same network per ssh and also ping it this way.

The Problem is, that anything out of my network can't connect to / ping my server. I already tried to deactivate the firewall on the router, but as i can't even ping it that shouldn't be the problem, right?

So maybe there is an issue caused by using the ipv6-adress?

After a long time i tried to ping another pc in my homenetwork and it also doesn't work. So i don't think the problem is caused by the server, but by the router.

I really don't know anything else to try, and i am verry grateful for some answers helping me to get that fixed.

Thank you verry much, just right now!

P.S.: sorry for my bad english ;)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have installed the SSH server if you want to connect then if you want to connect from another router you need to make sure you've opened port 22.

BTW: I got a similar problem but in my case it won't accept my login credentials when I login from another IP.
Link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/645881/i-cant-login-from-another-location-on-my-lubuntu-ubuntu-server